# Thymeleaf: Meaning of action parameter in form which already has th:action

Tags: thymeleaf

I´m just starting with Thymeleaf and have a code example with a form like this:

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/register}" method="post" th:object="${user}">
```

I understand th:action have the controller´s path to send a populated user object, but I can´t figure out why to use action="#".

Please enlighten me.

Comment: The `action="#"` attribute will be overridden by `th:action`, so you don't really need it. Why someone would ever need it, you ask? Well, the beauty of Thymeleaf is that you are able to preview the HTML template directly in the browser at design time. You may set any HTML attribute value that will be overridden by TH at run time, but would be important for design view. For example, the HTML form attribute `action` may be used in corresponding JavaScript code, so you set this attribute to some value and JS code will not get `null` when accessing it.

Comment: Thanks, Slava, very clear. Trying to understand it I could check what you explain, because removing the action nothing happened at all.

Comment: Just to add: This concept is referred to in the Thymeleaf world as [natural templating](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf).